# Performance problems after updating statistics SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, performance

I've received a database that was previously on SQL Server 2008R2 but was just put on a SQL Server 2014 instance. There were no maintenance tasks run of any kind run on the database since 2014 (e.g. Rebuilding of indexes, updating statistics, etc.).

Once we ran update statistics as part of our regularly scheduled maintenance that we do on a set schedule, the performance of some queries has taken a massive hit to the point where some select statements will seem to never finish.

The queries have some `CASE...WHEN` statements in them, but I wouldn't expect there to be such a performance hit.  Does anybody have any thoughts on what might cause such issues?

I've tried updating the compatibility level to 120 since it was on 100 when the database first came in but, that didn't make any difference on the performance.

Comment: Are the execution plans different depending the compatibility level? Generally, it's not uncommon for bad plans (or what would have been bad plans if stats were up-to-date) to become worse after an upgrade. Query and index tuning often addresses that problem.

Comment: Cross post or move this to http://dba.stackexchange.com/. You might get valuable recommendations from there also.

Comment: Thank you, i've moved it to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have only just moved the database, give the system some time to build up its execution plans and cache. Also, do your index maintenance and then something like this for the stats. Dont use sp_updatestats though as it just uses a sample of data not a full scan.

what results do you get for this:

```
SELECT 
        [sch].[name] + '.' + [so].[name] AS [TableName] ,
        [ss].[name] AS [Statistic],
        [sp].[last_updated] AS [StatsLastUpdated] ,
        [sp].[rows] AS [RowsInTable] ,
        [sp].[rows_sampled] AS [RowsSampled] ,
        [sp].[modification_counter] AS [RowModifications],
        Convert (decimal(18,2),(convert(numeric,[sp].[modification_counter]) / convert(numeric,[sp].[rows]) * 100)) as [Percent_changed]
    FROM [sys].[stats] [ss]
        JOIN [sys].[objects] [so] ON [ss].[object_id] = [so].[object_id]
            JOIN [sys].[schemas] [sch] ON [so].[schema_id] = [sch].[schema_id]
                OUTER APPLY [sys].[dm_db_stats_properties]([so].[object_id],
        [ss].[stats_id]) sp
    WHERE [so].[type] = 'U'
        AND [sp].[modification_counter] > 0
        And [sp].[last_updated] < getdate()-1
    ORDER BY [Percent_changed] DESC
```